# How to create a prop.table() for a three dimension table?

Tags: r

Could you let know how I can get percentages in a `three dimensional` table. I know how to create percentages in a `two dimensional` table by runnin the following

```
p <-with(mtcars,tapply(carb,list(cyl,vs),length))
prop.table(p,2) # by column
```

However, if I can try to add another variable, I dont how to do?

```
p <- with(mtcars,tapply(carb,list(cyl,vs,gear),length))
```

Answer (score 17):

You can specify multiple levels of input to the `prop.table` function, where 1=row, 2=column, 3=strata etc etc

Simple example:

```
test <- 1:8
dim(test) <- c(2,2,2)
test
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8
```

Then you can do things like:

```
# % of all values in each stratum/sub-table
prop.table(test,3)

# row % within each stratum/sub-table
prop.table(test,c(3,1))

# column % within each stratum/sub-table
prop.table(test,c(3,2))
```

There might be a simple way to deal with `NA`s, but a roundabout version would be to set them as `0`'s and then reset as `NA`'s:

```
# set one of the values to NA as an example
test[7] <- NA

# do the procedure
nas <- is.na(test)
test[nas] <- 0
result <- prop.table(test,c(3,2))
result[nas] <- NA

result
, , 1

          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.3333333 0.4285714
[2,] 0.6666667 0.5714286

, , 2

          [,1] [,2]
[1,] 0.4545455   NA
[2,] 0.5454545    1
```

Comment: thanks, how do I deal with NA? if one of the element is NA, prop.table() doesn't like it?

prop.table(test,c(3,2),na.rm=TRUE) wont work either?

Comment: @user16403 - see my edit for one method, though there may be simpler

Comment: I don't think you need to replace the 0 with NA in the results. 0 is a valid result.

Comment: @mnel - What if by definition you could not fall into that category? A `NA` may be more fitting than a `0` e.g - surgical complications by sex with one of the complication categories being "birth complications"?

Comment: I would expect 0 birth complications to male mothers, but I can see your point. This would have to be a case-by-case basis though.

Comment: thanks for that. What will I do if I would like to know the percentage difference between Cyl 4 and Cyl8 in each group?

Comment: @LuoLei - I'd open a new question clearly explaining what you are looking to do - the comments section isn't really appropriate to keep building on a question.

Comment: This is brilliant! I would never have thought that prop.table would allow you to do this. Your solution solved a difficult problem I was having in computing "by.row" proportions for subfactors in a large data.frame. Now with "xtabs" plus your trick with "prop.table" my problem is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `reshape2` and `acast` to create your three dimensional table. This will have `0` instead of `NA` for those values with no data.

```
library(reshape2)
tables  <- acast(mtcars, cyl~vs~gear,value.var = 'carb', fun.aggregate = 'length')
 tables
, , 3

   0 1
4  0 1
6  0 2
8 12 0

, , 4

  0 1
4 0 8
6 2 2
8 0 0

, , 5

  0 1
4 1 1
6 1 0
8 2 0

prop.table(tables, 2:3)

, , 3

  0         1
4 0 0.3333333
6 0 0.6666667
8 1 0.0000000

, , 4

  0   1
4 0 0.8
6 1 0.2
8 0 0.0

, , 5

     0 1
4 0.25 1
6 0.25 0
8 0.50 0
```

You could also use `table` instead of your `tapply` call

```
with(mtcars,table(cyl, vs ,gear))

, , gear = 3

   vs
cyl  0  1
  4  0  1
  6  0  2
  8 12  0

, , gear = 4

   vs
cyl  0  1
  4  0  8
  6  2  2
  8  0  0

, , gear = 5

   vs
cyl  0  1
  4  1  1
  6  1  0
  8  2  0
```

and then use `prop.table` on the appropriate dimensions

Comment: thanks for that. What will I do if I would like to know the percentage difference between Cyl 4 and Cyl8 in each group?

Comment: In the first group, gear=5
the percentage of Cyl4 is 25% (1) and the percentage of Cyl8 is 50% (2), I woudl ike to susbract 25% from 50%. How would I do that?

As I am dealing market satisfaction data. I need to work the net promotion score (i.e Percentage of Extremely Satifactied minus the Extremely Dissatisfied.....