# Calculations proportions of a three way table

Tags: arrays, r, percentage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a prop.table() for a three dimension table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151394/how-to-create-a-prop-table-for-a-three-dimension-table)

I am new to **R**, and I have been working on a three way table and need some help. Here is the table description via `dput`:

```
mytable <- structure(c(42L, 151L, 313L, 69L, 22L, 46L, 47L, 24L, 17L, 36L, 108L, 16L), .Dim = c(2L, 2L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("0", "1" ), c("female", "male"), c("adult", "child", "unknown")), class = "table")
```

I would like to access elements of this table by using the attribute names. For example:
`mytable["0"]["female"]["adult"]`Is it possible to do this ?

Also, I am trying to calculate proportions. Here is my table....

```
, , adult

      female male
    0     42  313
    1    151   69

    , , child

      female male
    0     22   47
    1     46   24

    , , unknown

      female male
    0     17  108
    1     36   16
```

I would like to calculate proportions for age group-sex-0|1.  When I run `prop.table(mytable)`it is calculating proportions of the cells, but it is considering all the three age groups.

```
, , adult

          female       male
    0 0.04713805 0.35129068
    1 0.16947250 0.07744108

    , , child

          female       male
    0 0.02469136 0.05274972
    1 0.05162738 0.02693603

    , , unknown

          female       male
    0 0.01907969 0.12121212
    1 0.04040404 0.01795735
```

I want proportions for each age group and sex. For example: Of all the adults, females with 1 are 78 %. How do we do this ?

Comment: could you post the output of `dput(mytable)`?

Comment: structure(c(42L, 151L, 313L, 69L, 22L, 46L, 47L, 24L, 17L, 36L, 
108L, 16L), .Dim = c(2L, 2L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("0", "1"
), c("female", "male"), c("adult", "child", "unknown")), class = "table")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are chasing?

The data:

```
test <- structure(c(42L, 151L, 313L, 69L, 22L, 46L, 47L, 24L, 17L, 36L, 108L, 16L), .Dim = c(2L, 2L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("0", "1" ), c("female", "male"), c("adult", "child", "unknown")), class = "table")
```

Get the column percentages (`2`) within each sub-table (`3`):

```
prop.table(test,c(2,3))
```

Results in:

```
, , adult

     female      male
0 0.2176166 0.8193717
1 0.7823834 0.1806283

, , child

     female      male
0 0.3235294 0.6619718
1 0.6764706 0.3380282

, , unknown

     female      male
0 0.3207547 0.8709677
1 0.6792453 0.1290323
```

Comment: thank you. this is what i was chasing. can you just help me understand, what c(2,3) is doing ?

Comment: @ShanthanKesharaju - when you do `prop.table` you select what part of the table you wish to get the percentages for. `1` gives row percentages, `2` gives column percentages, `3` gives percentages inside sub-tables. Then you can combine them, so `c(2,3)` gives you the column percentages within each sub-table.

Comment: great, just a follow up question. will there ever be a cased when it can be greater than 3, like 4 or 5

Comment: @ShanthanKesharaju - yep, if you keep tabling variables you can get 4,5, to Infinity dimension arrays which you will then get the proportion within that dimension using `prop.table(tablename,5)` eg: `structure(1:32,dim=c(2,2,2,2,2))` is a five dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

an easier way may be to make your table a data.frame:

```
df <- as.data.frame(mytable)
```

then to get the values for zero as you wanted with:

```
df[df$Var1 == 0,]
```

For proportions you could then do:

```
df <- transform(df,total = ave(Freq, Var3, FUN = sum))
# get totals within adult/child/unkown

df <- transform(df,props = Freq/total)
# make proportions



#    > df
#   Var1   Var2    Var3 Freq total      props
#1     0 female   adult   42   575 0.07304348
#2     1 female   adult  151   575 0.26260870
#3     0   male   adult  313   575 0.54434783
#4     1   male   adult   69   575 0.12000000
#5     0 female   child   22   139 0.15827338
#6     1 female   child   46   139 0.33093525
#7     0   male   child   47   139 0.33812950
#8     1   male   child   24   139 0.17266187
#9     0 female unknown   17   177 0.09604520
#10    1 female unknown   36   177 0.20338983
#11    0   male unknown  108   177 0.61016949
#12    1   male unknown   16   177 0.09039548
```