# Apply function for multidimensional array in R to find the mean for each column at each array

Tags: arrays, r, apply

```
z <- array(1:12, dim = c(2,2,3))
z
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9   11
[2,]   10   12
```

For the above array of 3 matrices, I would like to create one single matrix by taking the mean values of each column for each array. So my expected matrix dimension should be 3 by 2. The first entry should be the mean of 1 & 2. The second entry of the first row is the mean of 3 & 4. 
Can I use any apply function or any loop to create the matrix?
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Pretty sure i've answered this exact issue in the past as it is - `apply(z,c(3,2),mean)` - one moment and i'll find the duplicate.

Comment: Useful info here on how to specify multiple indexes to `apply` in a slightly different context - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151394/how-to-create-a-prop-table-for-a-three-dimension-table/13151629

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197330/using-apply-on-a-multidimensional-array-in-r

Comment: or `t(colMeans(z))`

Comment: @alistaire - I'm genuinely surprised that works given the result of `rowMeans(z)` !

Comment: @thelatemail It's sort of explained by the `dims` parameter docs: `Which dimensions are regarded as ‘rows’ or ‘columns’ to sum over. For row*, the sum or mean is over dimensions dims+1, ...; for col* it is over dimensions 1:dims.` Intuitively, it sort of makes sense that dims 1 and 3 are both horizontal "rows" in a cube of data and columns are still columns, but beyond 3 dimensions it's just random.